# Disable scrolling through tabs in chrome

Tags: xubuntu, 17.10, google-chrome

I am using chrome and I find it annoying when I scroll through tabs unintentionally using the scroll wheel. How can I disable it? I have tried to find it but to no avail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of early September 2018, there is no way to disable this really frustrating anti-feature without modifying the source code and recompiling Chromium.

A [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=407051) for an option to disable this absurd behavior was submitted in August 2014 and has languished for more than four years.

A [detailed solution](https://superuser.com/a/843598/33374) involving modifications to the Chromium source code (basically rolling back the patch that never should have been merged in the first place) is available on SuperUser.

Answer (score 14):

As of November 2021, if you enable the `chrome://flags/#scrollable-tabstrip` flag, the unwanted behaviour is disabled, although:

> This flag makes the tabs strip itself scrollable once there are enough open tabs to shrink the tabs down to a certain size (instead of keeping shrinking the tabs and eventually not show some as with the current behavior). When there are not enough tabs to need to scroll the tab strip, scrolling just has no effect.

Source: [Chromium issue #1255341](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1255341)

Comment: fantastic solution.. I've been setting this option to "disable" like a fool ( I never thought that "enabled" will do the job)

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer. This solved my issue.

Comment: Once again: set this flag to ENABLED if you want tab scroll to be disabled.